# how i can merge two object array data based on the similar filed checking

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, array-merge

I have two object array which contain low and high value , how can i merge them by checking the similar filed like date and combine them as low and high and return an array .

```
data = {
    low: [
        { date: '2020-09-17', value: '50' },
        { date: '2020-09-18', value: '52' },
        { date: '2020-09-15', value: '45' },
    ],

    high: [
        { date: '2020-09-17', value: '70' },
        { date: '2020-09-18', value: '75' },
        { date: '2020-09-15', value: '80' },
    ],
};

// Expected Output new array with date sort:
[
    { date: '2020-09-18', value: '52/75' },
    { date: '2020-09-17', value: '70/50' },
    { date: '2020-09-15', value: '45/80' },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved through [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as follows:

```js
data = {
    low: [
        { date: '2020-09-17', value: '50' },
        { date: '2020-09-18', value: '52' },
        { date: '2020-09-15', value: '45' },
    ],
    high: [
        { date: '2020-09-17', value: '70' },
        { date: '2020-09-18', value: '75' },
        { date: '2020-09-15', value: '80' },
    ],
};

let result = data.low.map(oLow => {
  oLow.value += '/' + data.high.find(oHigh => oHigh.date == oLow.date).value;
  return oLow;
});
result.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map`, `find` and `sort`

```
const res = data.low.map(l => ({
  date: l.date,
  value: `${l.value}/${data.high.find(h => h.date === l.date).value}`
})).sort((a,b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date))
```

```js
const data = {
  low: [
      { date: '2020-09-17', value: '50' },
      { date: '2020-09-18', value: '52' },
      { date: '2020-09-15', value: '45' },
  ],

  high: [
      { date: '2020-09-17', value: '70' },
      { date: '2020-09-18', value: '75' },
      { date: '2020-09-15', value: '80' },
  ],
};

const res = data.low.map(l => ({
  date: l.date,
  value: `${l.value}/${data.high.find(h => h.date === l.date).value}`
})).sort((a,b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date))

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```